# Invalid_grant when using cURL to connect to Xero with OAuth 2.0 and Filemaker

Tags: curl, filemaker, xero-api

I'm using `FileMaker Pro` to update a database from using `OAuth 1.0a` to `2.0` for use with `Xero` but have run into a problem.

I can successfully authorize the app (step 1) and parse the returned code and state. 
I then need to send the code back to the token endpoint (https://identity.xero.com/connect/token) with specific headers and body. This is where I'm stuck.

Here's what's needed: A POST Request containing the following

Header 1:

```
Authorization: "Basic " + base64encode(client_id + ":" + client_secret)

Header 2:

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Request Body:

```
grant_type=authorization_code

&code=xxxxxx

&redirect_uri=https://redirecturl.com
```

What I have done in `Filemaker` is a `"Insert from URL"` with the following `cURL` options: (And the `Xero` token endpoint as the specified URL)

```
"-X POST" &

" -H \"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\"" &

" -H \"Authorization: Basic "& Base64EncodeRFC (4648; token::client_id &":"& token::client_secret ) & "\"" &

" -d grant_type=authorization_code&code="&token::code&"&redirect_uri=https://redirecturl.com"
```

However when running the script it always responds with an error, invalid_grant.

I checked and am 99% sure the redirect url is consistent throughout the whole process

I'm new to `cURL` and am assuming there must be something with my syntax that I can't figure out, and ideas on what it could be and any help at all is greatly appreciated!

Thanks heaps

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `--data-urlencode` curl option instead of `-d`. And you may wanna put each query param in its own line in the cURL calc.

Something like this:

```
"-X POST" &

" -H \"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\"" &

" -H \"Authorization: Basic " & Base64EncodeRFC (4648; token::client_id &":"& token::client_secret ) & "\"" &

" --data-urlencode \"grant_type=authorization_code\"" &
" --data-urlencode \"code=" & token::code & "\"" &
" --data-urlencode \"redirect_uri=https://redirecturl.com\""
```